# Enable or disable the next button based on a live text control value in Wix?

Tags: user-interface, wix, controls, conditional-statements

I created a custom dialog page in wix and it has a text box. I want to disable the next button of the installer if the text box is empty end enable it if the user has typed a value. The following code works partially. It does not disable the next button but it does not navigate to the next page unless you fill the value. The problem I have is that the status of the next button is not updated while you are typing a value in the edit text box. If I remove the value from the edit text box and then click back to the previous screen and then next, the next button is disabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
 <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="MyCustomDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Custom Dialog Options">
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
          <Condition Action="disable">USERNAME1 = ""</Condition>
          <Condition Action="enable">NOT(USERNAME1 = "")</Condition>
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">NOT(USERNAME1 = "")</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Back">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Please type the value" />

        <Control Id="UserNameText" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="13"  NoPrefix="yes" Text="Please type the username" />
        <Control Id="UserNameEdit" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="72" Width="290" Height="18" Multiline="no" Property="USERNAME1"/>

      </Dialog>
    </UI>
 </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 9):

Disabling and enabling the "Next" button is nearly impossible in WIX. The answer from @Wjdavis5 disabled the "Next" button for me but the button will only enable if the user clicks in another text box. Which is confusing.

The following code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533736/how-do-i-require-a-value-in-a-textbox-in-a-wix-custom-dialog). It shows a single text entry box, when the user clicks "Next" it either shows an error dialog, or progresses to the install screen.

```
<Dialog Id="UserRegistrationDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
    <Control Id="UserIdEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18" Property="UserID" Text="{80}" />

    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next" >
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">2</Publish>
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="UserIdError"><![CDATA[UserID = ""]]></Publish>
    </Control>
</Dialog>

<Dialog Id="UserIdError" Width="260" Height="85" NoMinimize="no" Title="[ProductName]"> 
    <Control Id="UserIdErrorDesc" Type="Text" Width="194" Height="30" X="48" Y="15" Text="Please enter a User ID." />
    <Control Id="UserIdErrorOk" Type="PushButton" X="97" Y="57" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Ok">
      <Publish  Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Good idea, I am using this workaround to validate the input using result from custom action.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it.

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next">
      <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[InDBCONNECTION_STRING_VALID = "1"]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[InDBCONNECTION_STRING_VALID = "0"]]></Condition>
</Control>
```

Comment: Do you want to try answering another Wix question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355537/wix-setting-install-folder-correctly/